# Ball collision with independently rotating rectangles controlled by key down detection

Tags: collision-detection, collision, rotational-matrices

I am building a pong esque game where the paddles rotate indepedently around the centre point of either rectangle. Rotation is controlled via keydown functions I've set up using a/s or left/right arrows. I've stumbled across this code https://gist.github.com/snorpey/8134c248296649433de2and wrote it into my own.

Then I try to use an if function as follows to supposedly bounce the ball off the rotated  pad.

```
if (collision = true) {
      ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
      ballSeepdY = -ballSpeedY
  }
```

It seems the game thinks collision is always true because the ball jitters towards the top left corner of the canvas. 
I'm also thinking the code in the link above will not work with way my code draws the rectangles.

Is there a known way to solve this - to get the ball to bounce off a rectangle which can be rotated using keydown?
Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If collision were always true, your ball would be moving one way and then the reverse equally as much, so it would be stuck in one spot.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Thanks for your input. collision must always be true. After editting the code directly from the link to use my var names, the ball just drops vertically withour moving in the horizontal plain. What I'm struggling with is why collison is true despite the ball not crossing the boundries of the rotated rectangle.

Comment: You need to post more of your code before anyone can work out what is going wrong.